# Why does my jquery ajax post to a django view always result in the error callback executing

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

My jquery looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/process_values/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {values:['1','2']},
    success:function(response){
        alert("success: " + response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
    },

});
```

My django view looks like the following:

```
@csrf_protect
def process_values(request):
    # do stuff
    print 'complete'
    return HttpResponse("success", mimetype="application/html")
```

The view is executing correctly, but the error callback is always called when it completes. Any idea why this is?

UPDATE: To those suggesting its a CSRF issue. Its not, I'm using the standard javascript for setting that cookie and I can see the token in my request on the django side.

UPDATE2: I've just realised that there is something else in my function that calls this ajax call which changes the behaviour. I've got a redirect which I wrote by using:

```
document.location.href="/main/";
```

When I comment out this line, the success callback is called. Wow, didn't think that would make a diffenence. Anybody know why this was causing a failure? Have moved this question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689606/jquery-anchor-tag-click-event-does-an-ajax-post-when-it-redirects-it-causes-err) since it is a different question. Closing this question.

Comment: what is the error can u say it?

Comment: Is that HttpResponse method sending back a properly-formed 200 (success) status code?

Comment: @Sedat - how can I get the error? xhr.statusText shows 'error'. None of the other params show an error message. There is no server error.

Comment: @Greg Not sure what a properly-formed 200 status code looks like. How would I know?

Comment: ZincX, you won't need to manually form it yourself. HttpResponse will be able to handle it one way or another; you'll have to dig into its API a bit. But to at least see what's going on, open a debugging tool like Firebug, go to its "Network activity" tab (in Firebug, simply "Net") and you'll be able to see the status codes for requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that I needed to set the location.href="/main/"; in my success function callback. The page was getting redirected during the ajax call which was causing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the csrf token in the post data, or make the view `@csrf_exempt`.

you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/process_values/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {values:['1','2'], csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
    success:function(response){
        alert("success: " + response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
    },

});
```

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. I've tried @csrf_exempt and I also tried your technique for passing the csrfmiddlewaretoken. Neither of those made any difference. I had already set up some javascript from the django documentation to fix the csrf token issue. So, I don't think the problem I'm experiencing is to do with csrf tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CSRF token to your request as of Django 1.2.5, to plug a security hole.

The Django people have posted recommended code for this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-ajax), which is what I would suggest using.

Here is a paste of the code in full, for the lazy. Make sure this code runs once (from a global JS file or whatnot), and then you don't have to worry about it after that:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }
    function safeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```