# Jquery anchor tag click event does an ajax post, when it redirects, it causes error callback to execute

Tags: jquery

My HTML which is at this url '/main/' contains the following link:

```
<a href="/main/" id="do_something">Do Something</a>
```

So, the link should do something and then refresh the page.

My jquery looks something like this:

```
$('#do_something').click(function(event) {

    var my_values = ['1','2'];

    $.ajax({
        url:"/process_values/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {values:my_values},
        success:function(response){
            alert("success: " + response);
        },
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
        },

    });
```

});

The post is executing correctly, but the error callback is always called when it completes.

If I prevent the link from being called using event.preventDefault();, the success function is executed. Why is this? And how do I get the page to update after the post call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `event.preventDefault()`, the user is directed to `/main/` (because it's the default behavior of an anchor). Unloading the page causes all pending (XmlHttp) requests to abort, thus triggering the `error` function (=request has not finished yet).

An overview:

- *click* `#do_something`
- *fires* `click` event -> Ajax request
- *follows* link to `/main/`.
- *page unloads* -> Cancel all requests
- *XHR aborted* -> `error` function triggered

If you want the page to open, add this at the `success` function:

```
location.href = "/main/";
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hard-code the link:

```
$('#do_something').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var linkTo = $(this).attr("href");
    var my_values = ['1','2'];
    $.ajax({
        url:"/process_values/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {values:my_values},
        success:function(response){
            alert("success: " + response);
            location.href = linkTo; //Redirect the user to the new page
        },
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: yes but you should still prevent the default action in your example

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked it when I copy-pasted & indented the example.

Answer (score 1):

the idea with Ajax is not to do a page reload at all but load data asynchronously (parts at a time)

if you really need to you should use `location.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

You couold do:

```
$('#do_something').click(function(event) {
    var hrefSaved = $(this).attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();

    var my_values = ['1','2'];

    $.ajax({
        url:"/process_values/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {values:my_values},
        success:function(response){
            alert("success: " + response);
            window.location.href = hrefSaved
        },
        error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
        },

       });
    });
```

in this way you prevent the default action, make an AJAX call and if the calls is successful redirect to the desired page